# how to stop a called function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 2 divs one is an object and one is the toggler,
in my function i need something like `.toggle()`  but that isn't possible in my type of code where i use it for.
What i want is i want the div be dragable trough the function but after i toggle the button again the function needs to stop.

**The structure i got needs to be like this it can't be changed.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  window.moveactive = 0;
  
  $(".move").on("click", function() {
    moveactive = 1 - moveactive;

    if (moveactive == 1) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "green");
      activedraging();
      console.log("drag on");
    }if (moveactive == 0) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "red");
      console.log("drag off");
    }

  });
});

window.activedraging = function() {
    $(".object").draggable();
}
```

```css
.move{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.object{
  background-color: RGB(211,211,211);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="move"></div>
<div class="object"></div>
```

is there any way i could toggle the function with this script or an alternative like timeouts?

Comment: Hmm .. I'm not sure what's the actual question, but usually `mousedown` event is used to detect a drag start ...

Comment: i got a whole drag and drop system that's what's going on but it is contenteditable as well, what i want is a toggle when class move is clicked it is draggable and when it is clicked again it isn't draggable but trough a function not by using .toggle()

Comment: You forgot to add `.draggable( 'disable' )` ( or whatever the correct parameter is ) to disable the dragging again.

Comment: In the documentation for [.draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) it mentions a "destroy" method that removes the draggable functionality, and a "disable" method that disables it.

Comment: i now added a new function called deactivedraging and added draggable destroy that seems to work fine!

Comment: event.stopPropagation() ...